# Cambiar el estilo de un DatePicker que se abre a través de un WebView

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Tengo una aplicación realizada con Android Studio que carga un formulario en un WebView. En dicho formulario hay un campo HTML `<input type="date">` Al  desplegarlo desde la aplicación (con un móvil que corre con Android 6 Marshmallow) se abre el datepicker nativo de esa versión de Android, es decir, el que muestra un diálogo con un calendario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría es que lo hiciese con el datepicker que se muestra con un spinner, ya que para mi caso es más usable:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora lo he intentado sin mucho éxito añadiendo la siguiente línea en el `styles.xml` que utiliza la aplicación (propuesto en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835126/datepicker-with-different-style-than-activity)):

`<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Spinner</item>`

Adjunto también mi `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web1);
        myWebView.loadUrl("miurldeprueba/test/formulario.php");

    }
}
```

Y su `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.asier.webviewtest.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web1"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

¿Como podría implementar este cambio?

Comment: finalmente pudiste hacer el ajuste ? ahorita necesito hacer un ajuste con respecto al tema de datepicker tipo spinner. si me puede colaborar le agradeceria. Mil Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías forzar a que utilice el tema Holo Light o Holo Dark.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                      //Todo your work here
                   }
               }, yy, mm, dd);

               dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

               dialog.show();
```

[Fuente](http://androidbreakdown.blogspot.com.ar/2017/01/convert-date-picker-dialog-calendar.html)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la he modificado añadiendo una posibilidad más que he probado con éxito.